# Como terminar a sessão do utilizador se este fechar página/aba?

Tags: php

Quando o utilizador faz login, este utilizador passa pela seguinte verificação em todas as páginas:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['start_login'])) { // se não tiver pego tempo que logou
$_SESSION['start_login'] = time(); //pega tempo que logou
// adiciona 30 segundos ao tempo e grava em outra variável de sessão
$_SESSION['logout_time'] = $_SESSION['start_login'] + 30*60; 
}

// se o tempo atual for maior que o tempo de logout
if(time() >= $_SESSION['logout_time']) { 
header("location:logout.php"); //vai para logout

} else {
$red = $_SESSION['logout_time'] - time(); // tempo que falta
//echo "Início de sessão: ".$_SESSION['start_login']."<br>";
//echo "Redirecionando em ".$red." segundos.<br>";
}
```

Se o utilizador se mantiver na página ele é redirecionado após 30 minutos. Tudo bem funciona. O problema é que se o utilizador fechar a página/aba (X) ele continua logado no sistema... Como poderei contornar isto? Alguma dica?

Comment: Ele continua logado porque as $_SESSIONS são destruídas somente quando o navegador é fechado. Se ainda quiser encerrar a sessão apenas porque ele fechou a aba, você terá que usar AJAX.

Comment: @ClaydersonFerreira Não consigo achar solução para resolver este problema. Poderia me disponibilizar um código exemplo para quando o utilizador fechar a aba eu possa executar uma query? Ai ja dava para adicionar na tabela do utilizador o seu status offline

Comment: Vou tentar montar um exemplo pra você, já já eu posto.

Comment: As `$_SESSIONS` **não** são destruídas *somente* quando o navegador é fechado! Pode-se abrir e fechar o navegador diversas vezes e ele não vai destruir o cookie da sessão se estiver marcada a opção de **continuar de onde parei**. É só uma observação!

Comment: @PapaCharlie, essa é nova pra mim. Valeu pela info (:

Comment: @ClaydersonFerreira pra mim também era novo, estava procurando umas questões sobre cookie no SO-EN um dia desses e me deparei com uma resposta que explicava isso. Em suma, o usuário desmarca a opção *permanecer conectado*, e mesmo assim o navegador mantém o cookie. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Vamos lá

Adicione uma tabela ao seu banco de dados, seguindo o modelo abaixo. Ela ficará responsável por gerenciar as sessões abertas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Altere a validação que você já tem, e troque pelo código abaixo. Lembre-se de fazer as modificações necessárias para o funcionamento com sua aplicação.

```
<?php

$host   = 'localhost';
$db     = 'banco';
$user   = 'root';
$pass   = '';
$charst = 'utf8';

$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$db};charset={$charst}", $user, $pass);

if (!isset($_SESSION['session_id'])) {

    $idAutenticado = false;
    while ($idAutenticado === false) {
        $novoID = rand();

        $consultarID = $pdo->prepare("SELECT `session_id` FROM `sessoes_abertas` WHERE `session_id` = :session_id");
        $consultarID->bindValue(':session_id', $novoID);
        $consultarID->execute();

        if ($consultarID->rowCount() === 0) {
            $idAutenticado = true;
        }
    }

    $cadastrarID = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `sessoes_abertas` (`session_id`, `last_activity`, `logout_time`) VALUES (:session_id, :last_activity, :logout_time)");
    $cadastrarID->bindValue(':session_id', $novoID);
    $cadastrarID->bindValue(':last_activity', time());
    $cadastrarID->bindValue(':logout_time', time() + (30 * 60));
    $cadastrarID->execute();

    $_SESSION['session_id'] = $novoID;
} else {
    $validarID = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `sessoes_abertas` WHERE `session_id` = :session_id AND `last_activity` >= :last_activity AND `logout_time` <= :logout_time");
    $validarID->bindValue(':session_id', $_SESSION['session_id']);
    $validarID->bindValue(':last_activity', (time() - (5 * 60)); //Permite até 5 minutos de inatividade
    $validarID->bindValue(':logout_time', (time() + (30 * 60)); //30 minutos de duração pra sessão
    $validarID->execute();

    if ($validarID->rowCount() === 0) {
        unset($_SESSION['session_id']);
        header('Location: ./');
    }
}
```

Agora temos que implementar a função AJAX que será responsável por atualizar o campo last_activity, dessa forma podemos garantir que o usuário está ativo.

**Obs:** o tempo de inatividade é definido na primeira parte do código, onde está comentado.

Inclua o jQuery no seu projeto

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

É possível fazer sem jQuery, usando JavaScript puro, o que seria mais recomendável caso sua aplicação não use o jQuery para outras funcionalidades, mas como não entendo quase nada de JS, vou deixar pra outra pessoa.

O código abaixo irá fazer requisições a um script PHP (que iremos criar mais adiante) a cada intervalo de tempo.

```js
<script>
    function attLastActivity() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'last-activity.php',
            type: 'GET',
            data: '',
            success: function(data) {
                //Essa função é disparada caso a requisição dê certo, se quiser implementar alguma funcionalidade, edite aqui.
            },
            beforeSend: function() {
                //Função disparada antes de fazer a requisição.
            }
        });
    }

    setInterval(attLastActivity, 30000); //Faz uma requisição a cada 30 segundos
</script>
```

Crie um arquivo PHP que irá receber as requisições AJAX, o nome do arquivo deve ser `last-activity.php` e adicione o código abaixo.

```
?php

if (isset($_SESSION['session_id'])) {
    $host   = 'localhost';
    $db     = 'banco';
    $user   = 'root';
    $pass   = '';
    $charst = 'utf8';

    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$db};charset={$charst}", $user, $pass);

    $lastActivity = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE `sessoes_abertas` SET `last_activity` = :last_activity WHERE `session_id` = :session_id");
    $lastActivity->bindValue(':last_activity', time());
    $lastActivity->bindValue(':session_id', $_SESSION['session_id']);
    $lastActivity->execute();
}
```

## Concluindo

Se o usuário fechar a aba, e ficar 5 minutos sem voltar, ele perde a sessão. Esse tempo pode ser personalizado na primeira parte.

Dessa forma, você terá que quer, mas todos os registros irão continuar no banco e, dependendo da quantidade de acessos a sua aplicação, isso pode ficar muito grande e reduzir o desempenho do banco de dados, portanto, você também pode criar funções para deletar as IDs que expiraram.

Recomendo que faça isso utilizando cron jobs (se estiver em ambiente Linux).

Vale ressaltar que não é obrigatório usar PDO para conectar-se ao banco de dados, isso depende da sua aplicação.

É isso, lembre-se que o código deve ser modificado conforme suas necessidades.

Comment: Obrigado pelo seu tempo amigo, coloquei como tópico resolvido porque parece ser mesmo essa a solução! contudo vou experimentar e logo digo alguma coisa. Mais uma vez obrigado!(:

Comment: É ajudando que se aprende rs. Qualquer dúvida referente ao código, só comentar aqui que eu te explico.